# How to find out who (what process) is starting another process?

Tags: linux, spam-prevention, pid, exim

So no matter how many times I kill exim4 it immediately comes back to life. I have stopped the service and everything but something is bringing it back to life and using it for spamming.

How do I find who is the culprit, in other words, who is starting the exim process?

```
$ ps -ef | grep exim
root      3038     1  0 14:48 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5Mf-0000mt-L7
107       3042  3038  0 14:48 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5Mf-0000mt-L7
root      5083     1  0 14:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5N0-0001Jr-88
107       5233  5083  0 14:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5N0-0001Jr-88
root      7420     1  0 14:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5NR-0001vb-Km
107       7430  7420  0 14:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5NR-0001vb-Km
root      7454     1  0 14:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5NR-0001wA-Rl
107       7478  7454  0 14:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5NR-0001wA-Rl
root      7518     1  0 14:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5NS-0001xF-8C
107       7523  7518  0 14:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5NS-0001xF-8C
root      8863     1  0 14:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5Nm-0002Ir-93
107       8866  8863  0 14:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5Nm-0002Ir-93
root      8876     1  0 14:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YR5Nm-0002J5-Ee
```

Comment: you might try restricting the exim binary (take away execute), and then checking dmesg to see what app complains about it.

Comment: That's a great idea, Frank. How do I tail dmesg?

Comment: depends on your system, but on my debian box, its `sudo tail /var/log/dmesg` . on ubuntu you can just say `tail dmesg`. and don't forget to check other logs. as well. the debug log may not get notified of that failure, but hopefully sys or messages does.

Comment: I am on UBUNTU. Checking `/var/log/dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog` but don't see anything there. Are you sure this permission error shows up there?

Comment: like I said, not always. it is up to the developer to decide whether or not to write debug messages. instead check the sys/messages/auth logs, and see what you see.

Answer (score 11):

A direct answer to your question (but not your problem) would be: `ps -axjf`. That's `a` and `x` to see "all" processes (see [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) for a more elaborate explanation of these parameters), `j` for jobs format and `f` for the fancy ASCII art tree. The ppid (first column) shows the parent process ID.

A more direct approach to check the PPid of a specific process would be to check the PPid in `/proc/<processid>/status`, like this: `grep PPid /proc/2774/status`.

Now let's focus on your problem. With the information you provided, my guess is that you're trying to kill one of the mail *delivery* processes (in most configurations, exim spawns a separate process for each message to be delivered under user `root`). These processes use the `-Mc` option. From the [Exim manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/exim):

> -MC <transport> <hostname> <sequence number> <message id>
>
> This option is not intended for use by external callers. It is used internally by
>   Exim to invoke another instance of itself to deliver a waiting message
>   using an existing SMTP connection, which is passed as the standard
>   input. This must be the final option, and the caller must be root or
>   the Exim user in order to use it.

There is a queue runner process (often found in ps like: `/usr/local/exim-in/bin/exim -bd -q 10m` under user `mail`; not `root`). Probably that's the parent process. Note that exim often has more than one queue runner process. To inspect what's going on - process-wise - you can use the `ps` command mentioned earlier.

You might want to check what messages are queuing up in your mail queue (and why).